# How to improve performance of dataframe slices matching?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance, match

I need to improve the performance of the following dataframe slices matching.
What I need to do is find the matching *trips* between 2 dataframes, according to the *sequence* column values with order conserved.

My 2 dataframes:

```
>>>df1
  trips sequence
0   11  a
1   11  d
2   21  d
3   21  a
4   31  a
5   31  b
6   31  c

>>>df2
  trips sequence
0   12  a
1   12  d
2   22  c
3   22  b
4   22  a
5   32  a
6   32  d
```

Expected output:

```
['11 match 12']
```

This is the following code I' m using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'trips': [11, 11, 21, 21, 31, 31, 31], 'sequence': ['a', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'trips': [12, 12, 22, 22, 22, 32, 32], 'sequence': ['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd']})

route_match = []
for trip1 in df1['trips'].drop_duplicates():
    for trip2 in df2['trips'].drop_duplicates():
        route1 = df1[df1['trips'] == trip1]['sequence']
        route2 = df2[df2['trips'] == trip2]['sequence']
        if np.array_equal(route1.values,route2.values):
            route_match.append(str(trip1) + ' match ' + str(trip2))
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Despite working, this is very time costly and unefficient as my real dataframes are longer.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Should 11 match 32 as well?

Comment: @DanielF no as matching already occured on 12

Comment: Why is not matched `32` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate each trip as tuple with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas-pydata-org.translate.goog/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.htm), then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) the two outputs to identify the identical routes:

```
out = pd.merge(df1.groupby('trips', as_index=False)['sequence'].agg(tuple),
               df2.groupby('trips', as_index=False)['sequence'].agg(tuple),
               on='sequence'
              )
```

output:

```
   trips_x sequence  trips_y
0       11   (a, d)       12
1       11   (a, d)       32
```

If you only want the first match, [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) the output of `df2` aggregation to prevent unnecessary merging:

```
out = pd.merge(df1.groupby('trips', as_index=False)['sequence'].agg(tuple),
               df2.groupby('trips', as_index=False)['sequence'].agg(tuple)
                  .drop_duplicates(subset='sequence'),
               on='sequence'
              )
```

output:

```
   trips_x sequence  trips_y
0       11   (a, d)       12
```